# NSURLConnection - Disable the authentication challenge response mechanism

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

**SITUATION**

- Using AFNetworking (NSURLConnection) to access my server API
- The API needs Basic Authentication with token as username
- The API returns HTTP 401 when token is invalid
- I set the Basic Authentication headers before any request
- If it returns 401, I retry like this:

  ```
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [MyHTTPClient.sharedClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      processSuccessBlock(operation, responseObject);
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      processFailureBlock(operation, error);

      if (operation.response.statusCode == 401)
          [MyHTTPClient.sharedClient refreshTokenAndRetryOperation:operation success:processSuccessBlock failure:processFailureBlock];
  }];
  ```

**PROBLEM**

- When the server returns HTTP 401 with a Basic Authentication challenge, AFNetworking/NSURLConnection **sends the identical request twice** (initial request and then in answer to the authentication challenge)
- But because of the code above that I handle the HTTP 401 myself, **this is totally unnecessary**  and I want it to stop answering the authentication challenge automatically

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- Responding with `cancelAuthenticationChallenge:` to `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` is aborting the second call, but it gives the error code -1012 (NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication) instead of 401 and masks the real response

**How do you disable the authentication challenge response mechanism so you get the servers response without calling it twice?**

Comment: set username and password in request :


[self.request setUsername:username];
[self.request setPassword:password];

Comment: @GauravPatel set username on what class? how does this disable the authentication challenge?

Comment: How are you setting the authentication for the first request?

Comment: @mackross `[self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"token" password:@"x"]` in `AFHTTPClient`

Comment: Why would you want to disable this?  An auth challenge is normally a fatal error (for the request).  The fact that Apple allows you to retry your connection is a feature, not a hindrance.

Comment: Have you tried setting `.shouldUseCredentialStorage` to `NO` on the operation before enqueing it? On second thought that probably wont work. I'll think some more.

Comment: Perhaps try `useCredential:nil forAuthenticationChallenge:`
or `continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:`
 or `rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge:`? One of them might give you the correct behaviour. If not I think you might have come up against a rare case where AFNetworking doesn't give you enough flexibility.

Comment: @CodaFi I don't use the built in authentication challenge functionality. I have my own way to handle 401 status and listening for this response. But because of this I explained above, I can either let it do two requests and then I receive the 401, or I can cancel the authentication challenge, but then I don't get the real response with the 401 code.

Comment: @mackross thanks for trying to help. `continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:`will make another request. I can't see a response that only cancels the authentication challenge and give me the real response in return.

Comment: Then you've backed yourself into an artificially created corner. Why do software developers do this?  We're supposed to be the smart ones.

Comment: @thejaz did you try rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge?

Comment: @thejaz  Did you find a solution?  I am looking at the exact same issue.  I want to handle the 401 myself, but AFNetworking is attempting a re-authentication. Not clear on the answers below on how to implement a way to override that behavior.   Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a few of options to fully customize the authentication handling:

1. Utilize `setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` and `setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:`  from class `AFURLConnectionOperation` and set corresponding blocks where you can tailor the mechanism you require.

   The headers contain documentation.
2. Override `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` in a subclass of `AFURLConnectionOperation`. This will effectively override the complete authentication mechanism setup in AFNetworking.

Note, that you cannot disable the "server validates client identity" authentication challenge -- this is part of the server. You *MUST* provide the correct credentials for the requested authentication method.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I have tried the `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` already. The question is how I make the client accept the 401 status code and don't send another request.

Comment: You received a status code 401 which means the server requires the client to provide credentials so that the server can validate the client's identity. The client can either cancel the request, or repeat the same request with the required authorization headers set up with the credentials. There is no other option.

Comment: I want to handle it myself, so the only thing I'm asking for is making it give me the 401 response directly instead of having me canceling it or do the request twice.

Comment: I think you don't understand: the only way to handle status code 401 (Unauthorized) as a client is to cancel the request or provide the credentials. You can't do anything else. See §10.4.2 [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper has got swagga. Best AFNetworking answer I've seen all week. Checkmark for you! #twerkrandomly

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I have the same issue and I want to manually cancel the request, and to some processing on the client.  I want to avoid AFNetworking to resend the request automatically.  Can you expand on how to set the blocks to do some client processing and cancel the request?

Comment: @agarcian You may find your answer in the official docs in chapter *Configuring Authentication* in [Making HTTP and HTTPS Requests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html) and here [Authentication Challenges and TLS Chain Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html). There's also an example. Based on this information you can find more specific help on SO (examples).

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    NSURLCredential *cred;
    cred = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
    [challenge.sender useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: This will effectively disable "client validates server identity", which is a "server trust authentication challenge". However, the OP specifically asked to disable "server validates client identity", when stating the problem: "When the server returns HTTP 401 with a *Basic Authentication challenge* ... " - which is not possible.