# Authentication challenge called in NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I'm creating NSURLConnection with a link https://www.wella.com which is finally passed to a `UIWebView`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[u stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
self.authRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
self.authConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:authRequest delegate:self];
```

I am unexpectedly receiving authentication challenge, which of course I am currently not handling.
I've noticed that when using desktop browser, when I paste the link above, it's address is automatically changed to https://www.wella.com/professional/countryselector

When pasting the extended link, `NSURLConnection` works without any problems.
How can I get rid of this challenge and could it be somehow connected with that link auto change?

EDIT: I've solved it. The question, however, remains: why does the auto link change causes calling the authentication challenge?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to: [Muralikrishna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525870/3466016)
I've managed it by implementing the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method and setting the trust credential:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    NSURLCredential *cred;
    cred = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
    [challenge.sender useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```